# How to test private method without using PowerMock (Use case: object creation)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have encapsulated the object creation into new method as specified in https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation [Pattern 1: using one-line methods for object creation]

I have used *private* before makeFoo method. Which is making my work harder.

Wasn't private necessary for makeFoo method?
If so how people handled it?

Comment: It might be better to explain *why* you want to mock object creation, it could well be possible that a better option altogether exists

Answer (score 1):

If you make the method `protected` you can override it in a test double of your SUT. This way you can make the method return some mock, spy or other type of test double.

If at all possible, however, I'd recommend you to inject the dependency class in the constructor. It saves you some headache and boiler plate code. There are cases where a protected factory method is a "better" solution though, just something to keep in mind.

EDIT: Example of constructor injection:

Going from this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.someDependency = new SomeDependency(new A(), new B());
    }

    public void doWork()
    {
        _someDependency.doSomething();
    }
}
```

To this

```
public class MyClass
{
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    public MyClass(SomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public void doWork()
    {
        this.someDependency.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This allows you to inject your class with a test double directly rather than inheriting it and overriding some factory method.

Comment: "There are cases where a protected factory method is a "better" solution though, just something to keep in mind." - Does this mean 'Pattern 2 - the factory helper pattern' in the above link is better option?

Comment: Added an example of constructor injection

Comment: Thanks. But I'm afraid that my case is different. Its something like `class SomeClass { SomeVariableType somevariable; public someReturnType doSomething() { SomeOtherNewClass obj = new SomeOtherNewClass(somevariable); } }`

Comment: You can still pull out the dependency (obj) into the constructor and assign it to a field. If you think that would make the class less maintainable due to a scope promotion you can pull it out to the local method parameters. The point is, don't make your class responsible for both creating dependencies AND doing work with them. It's part of the SOLID principles of OOP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)